# Office Graph change the rowlimit

Tags: search, office-365, rest, office-graph

How Can i Change the rowlimit in an Office Graph query? I tried adding rowlimit=20 to the search but it didn't work.

Comment: Might be an issue of case sensitivity, try `RowLimit`. Also, it would help to see your query

Comment: Still not working... I'm trying to query this: https://myDomain/_api/search/query?Querytext='*'&amp;Properties='GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\,OR(action\:1001\,action\:1003))'&amp;RowLimit=50

Comment: That semicolon before the `*` looks malplaced, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a typo

Comment: Ok, it's seems that the error is for the Graph part you should use &amp; but for the Search part you should use just the symbol &. So my url now is: myDomain/_api/search/query?Querytext='*'&RowLimit=50&amp;Properties='GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\,OR(action\:1001\,action\:1003))'